# Show or list newest file in directory.

Tags: windows, file-management

I'm using Windows 7. I'm looking for a graphical way to show the newest (most recently created or modified) file in a directory, including it's subfolders. I have a parent directory, with a couple thousand subdirectories within. I need to find the newest file within those subdirectories. I am willing to pay for an application that can display this information easily. I am trying to avoid applications that show me every file in each subdirectory, as there are several thousand.

Any suggestions would be great. Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [A way to find newest files in a directory, including subdirectories](http://superuser.com/questions/109264/a-way-to-find-newest-files-in-a-directory-including-subdirectories)

Comment: That thread dealt with programming, I am only searching for a graphical solution. I did check that thread before posting though.

Comment: That thread didn't deal with programming.  They just asked for a way, and suggested that scripts were acceptable.  so it's the same question IMO.  The one suggested answer is "Everything" which would give you a GUI list of files, sorted by the Date. If you are looking specifically for a piece of software that does XYZ (ie: GUI, no extra files shown, etc.) and will except no other answers, then your question is off-topic for SU, as we don't do software requests/suggestions.

Comment: I will accept alternative answers, I am just unfamiliar with scripting. I neglected to mention that this is a networked drive, so Everything did not work when I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I think Windows already has these information, so you don't need an external application to do this task. What you need to do is switch Window explorer view to `Detail` mode. Example my computer window:

[image]

You can see your needed information in `Date modified` tab and `Date created` tab. When you click to these tab, Windows will sort files (folders) for you in ascending or descending order of date. So, you can get the newest or oldest files, folders as you need.

If you don't see these tabs in your computer, right click on this bar and select them

[image]

Hope this help.